# BASH Substracting Files on Key line by line

Tags: bash, file, key, line

I just wanna to substract one CSV-File from another one, but not if the lines are the same. Instead of comparing the lines I'd like to look if the lines matching in one field.

e.g. the first file

```
EMAIL;NAME;SALUTATION;ID
foo@bar.com;Foo;Mr;1
bar@foo.com;Bar;Ms;2
```

and the second file

```
EMAIL;NAME
foo@bar.com;Foo
```

the resultfile should be

```
EMAIL;NAME;SALUTATION;ID
bar@foo.com;Bar;Ms;2
```

I think u know what I mean ;)

How is that possible in bash? It's easy for me doing this in Java, but I realy like to learn how to do that in bash. Also I can substract by comparing the lines using sort

```
#! / bin / bash    
echo "Substracting Files..."

sort "/tmp/list1.csv" "/tmp/list2.csv" "/tmp/list2.csv" | uniq -u >> /tmp/subList.csv

echo "Files successfully substracted."
```

But the lines arn't the same tuple. So I have to compare line with keys.

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.. Nils

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution coming to my mind is this one (working with bash):

```
grep -v -f <(cut -d ";" -f1 /tmp/list2.csv) /tmp/list1.csv
```

That means:
`cut -d ";" -f1 /tmp/list2.csv`: Extract the first column of the second file.
`grep -f some_file`: Use a file as pattern source.
`<(some_command)`: This is a process substitution. It executes the command and feeds the output to a named pipe which then can be used as file input to `grep -f`.
`grep -v`: Print only the lines not matching the pattern(s).

Comment: Nice, elegant use of unix-foo, no need for awk if cut/grep will do (although awk might be faster sometimes, there's no hard rules, and the results have surprised me many times)

Comment: Works fine in console, but using it in a shellscript caused that: /tmp/substract.sh: 4: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: @Nils: Do you use `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh`? The latter one will not work because *process substitution* is a `bash` feature.

Comment: I use the first `bash`one, the full script is `#! /bin/bash    
grep -v -f <(cut -d ";" -f1 /tmp/liste2.csv) /tmp/liste1.csv >> result.csv`

Comment: @Nils: That's strange. I tried your script and it worked without problems. It generated the file `result.csv`, containing `bar@foo.com;Bar;Ms;2` if I use the input of your example files.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** the solution to the question, via `join` and `awk`.

```
join --header -1 1 -2 1 -t";" --nocheck-order -v 1 1.csv 2.csv | | awk 'NR==1 {print gensub(";[^;]\\+$","","g");next} 1'
```

These were the inverse answers:

```
$ join -1 1 -2 1 -t";" --nocheck-order -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4 1.csv 2.csv 
EMAIL;NAME;SALUTATION;ID
foo@bar.com;Foo;Mr;1
```

`join` to the rescue.

Or the skipping of printing the NAME field without `-o`:

```
$ join -1 1 -2 1 -t";" --nocheck-order 1.csv 2.csv | awk 'BEGIN {FS=";" ; OFS=";"} {$NF=""; print }'
```

(But it still prints a plus `;`˛after the last field.

HTH

Comment: isn't that the inverse? can you make join return the line that cannot be joined?

Comment: but how to avoid the double field (name in your case), for me there are 5 matching field and it looks like a mess with all of them appending to the lines..

Comment: @sehe oh you are right, I missread it. Updating the answer. Thanks.